# Updating the values selected by "Select tag" in the state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to update the value in the state object according to the selected value in the select tag. I am using an event listener on that select tag. but when I am trying to select an item from the dropdown list, the event listener throws an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

in the event listener, I am updating my state using the

> [e.target.name] : e.target.value

this is my event listener :

```js
handleInput = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

this is my select tag. I am using antd for frontend designing.
Thank you

Comment: can you post your component code as well

Answer (score 0):

setState is async. React events are pooled https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html. So by the time `[e.target.name]` executes `e.target` is nullified.

```
 handleInput = (e) => {
 const eventObj= e.target;
 console.log(e.target.value);
 this.setState({ [eventObj.name]: eventObj.value });
}
```